# How to locate a link based on the value of preceding cell in the same table row

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to click the "Click to delete user" link based on the user's email in the same row as follows. Please suggest an XPath or other better option/options to find and click using Selenium Webdriver.

HTML of the table row is as follows:

```html
<tbody id="userlist">
<tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            auser1@gmail.com
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
             Student
        </td>
        <td class="status-img">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" onclick="javascript:confirmUserStatusChange(1,&quot;/User/UpdateStatus?userId=70070&amp;status=3&amp;URLID=ipcenyi87att6vfqib7szg&quot;)" data-original-title="Click to disable user"><i class="fa fa-user fa-green fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" onclick="javascript:user_editUser(&quot;/User/AddUser?userId=70070&amp;URLID=uazyqtod2f0w0oxqhjqasq&quot;)" data-original-title="Click to edit user"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" onclick="javascript:user_confirmDeleteUser(&quot;&quot;, &quot;/User/DeleteUser?userId=70070&amp;URLID=uazyqtod2f0w0oxqhjqasq&quot;)" data-original-title="Click to delete user"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work:

```
//tr[td[normalize-space()="auser1@gmail.com"]]/td/a[@data-original-title="Click to delete user"]
```

Comment: not working. I have tried //tr/td[contains(text(),"atifuser1@gmail.com")] and it selects the td with email but unable to figure out the part to click the link with data-original-title="Click to delete user"

Comment: How did you try? Did you use Implicit/Explicit wait? Share code line

Comment: I have used chrome dev tools